# list comprehension with multiple arguments

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, list-comprehension

Why can't I do like this in Haskell?

```
[a * b | a <- [0..b], b <- [0..10]]

error: Variable not in scope: b
```

If this is impossible using the list comprehension? Or what else can I do to achieve the goal?

Comment: What goal are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The nested loop, but the second loop will use the first loop variable

Comment: Your code is trying to use the second variable in the first loop.

Comment: @melpomene Yep, but how?

Comment: What do you mean, how? You wrote it. It's right there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "extractions" are processed from left to right, so when you try to get a value for `a`, `b` *isn't* defined yet.

A list comprehension is just syntactic sugar for the following monadic code, which makes it easier to see why `b` isn't in scope yet.

```
-- [a * b | a <- [0..b], b <- [0..10]]
[0..b] >>= \a -> [0..10] >>= \b -> return (a * b)
```

Flip it around, and `b` comes into scope:

```
-- [a * b | b <- [0..10], a <- [0..b]]
[0..10] >>= \b -> [0..b] >>= \a -> return (a*b)
```

Answer (score 4):

`b` needs to be in scope before the `[0..b]` part:

```
[a * b | b <- [0..10], a <- [0..b]]
```